# Async's each immediately prints out all elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, foreach

So, I have an array of three objects. They have a name and a type property (and various others). I want to loop through each of them and use the `readline` module to get user input for all of them. Here's the javascript code I use to do this (using the `async` module):

```
async.each(questions.q, function (e, cb) {
  if (e.type === "s") {
    //not important
  } else if (e.type === "q") {
    rl.question(e.name, function (a) {
      //do stuff
      cb();
    });
  }
}, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

(`question.q` is the array of elements)

However, the output for all three of my objects with the `type` `q` is the following:

```
Question1Question2Question3 //input
```

Instead of doing one at a time, `each` prints all 3 out and then awaits an input. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be running these asynchronously if you don't want this behavior but I suppose you could emulate a locking mechanism pretty easily with a numbered variable if you wanted to keep the code using async.

Comment: @ShaneQful I thought running these asynchronously was the right thing to do? It waits until the stuff has been done and then moves on to the next one, right?

Comment: so you want them to run one at a time? try eachSeries

Comment: @kyr No running one at a time and moving on to the next is synchronous behavior. With asynchronous behavior they are running at the same time and order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @aembke That works! I'm surprised I didn't see that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by using `async.eachSeries()` instead of `async.each()`. `async.each()` iterates over the collection in parallel (you can limit the concurrency with `async.eachLimit()`), whereas `async.eachSeries()` iterates over the collection in series (one at a time).