# async each variable scope in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I am using async each to loop through and constructing an object called `coupon_bo`. Surprisingly inside `processbo` function, I am seeing a side effect where only the last copy of `coupon_bo` object is available to `processbo` function.

My understanding is that since `coupon_bo` is local to each iteration, there should be a new object for iteration.

Am I missing something?

```
function hitApplyLogic(coupon_names, coupons_list, req, callback) {
    async.each(coupon_names, function(coupon_name, callback) {
        var coupon_bo = new coupon_objects.CouponsBO();
        coupon_bo.incoming_request = req.body;
        coupon_bo.incoming_request['coupon_code'] = coupon_name.cn;
        coupon_bo.incoming_request['list_offers'] = true;

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            console.log("CONSOLE-BO: " + JSON.stringify(coupon_bo));

        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: please put some more code, like where are you calling callback and all

Comment: async.each() run asynchronously and may corrupt your data `coupon_bo`. You may like to use `async.eachSeries()`  or use `this.coupon_bo` rather than `var coupon_bo`

Comment: @suraj99934 callback is called inside the function(result) {}

Comment: can you replace this `async.each(coupon_names, function(coupon_name, callback) {` with `async.eachLimit(coupon_names, 1, function(coupon_name, callback) {` and check problem is still occuring?

Comment: @suraj99934 see the updated code. It reproduces the problem which is happening. Always last BO is printed in console.log. I guess that's behaviour of each, it doesn't create a new scope

Comment: no that is not true, check this code
`var async = require('async');
var coupon_names = [1, 2, 3, 4];
async.each(coupon_names, function(coupon_name, callback) {
    var coupon_bo = {};
    coupon_bo[Math.random().toString()] = "hi";
    setTimeout(function() {
        //callback is called here
        console.log(coupon_bo);
        callback()
    }, 500);
});`

Comment: It will always crete a new variable `coupon_bo`

Comment: What version of async you are using, can you try on 1.4 @suraj99934

Comment: checked with 1.4.2 also, all the `coupon_bo` objects are different,
here is the output of my program `{ '0.35520064564570686': 'hi' }
{ '0.926551623613157': 'hi' }
{ '0.45901556838783253': 'hi' }
{ '0.13620334446253368': 'hi' }`

Answer (score 1):

`async.each` has no guarantee of running the tasks in order.

Per the [documentation:](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

> Note, that since this function applies iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

I'm not sure what you meant by `processbo` function. But `var coupon_bo` should be unique to each instance of the iteratee that is ran. So there should be no issue of it being overwritten by the other ones.

I'm also not sure why you're using `setTimeout` to log `coupon_bo` after 1s.

I did find something missing in your implementation which is the call to the `callback` function in the iteratee
    `async.each(coupon_names, function(coupon_name, callback) {`

Without calling it you'll be forever stuck at `async.each`

```
function hitApplyLogic(coupon_names, coupons_list, req, callback) {
    async.each(coupon_names, function(coupon_name, eachCallback) { //Changed callback to eachCallback to avoid confusion with the one received in hitApplyLogic
        var coupon_bo = new coupon_objects.CouponsBO();
        coupon_bo.incoming_request = req.body;
        coupon_bo.incoming_request['coupon_code'] = coupon_name.cn;
        coupon_bo.incoming_request['list_offers'] = true;

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            console.log("CONSOLE-BO: " + JSON.stringify(coupon_bo));
            eachCallback(null); // Finished doing all the work with this particular coupon_name
        }, 1000);
    },
    , function(err) { //This function is called once all the coupon_names were processed

        if(err) {
          // One of the coupon_names returned an error
          console.log('One of the coupon_names returned an error');
          return callback(err); // Callback received in hitApplyLogic
        } else {
          // Everything went OK!
          console.log('All coupons were constructed');
          return callback(null); // Callback received in hitApplyLogic
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution for your problem, [Async's each immediately prints out all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027023/asyncs-each-immediately-prints-out-all-elements#26027502)

`async.eachSeries()` will iterate array item one at a time, where `async.each()` will iterate all the items at once in parallel.

Comment: I need the parallelism

Comment: If you want parallel operation without error iterating, I suggest you to use `async.waterfall` (http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall) inside `async.each` to call your function on every iteratiion.